# "Прошляпить"

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Почему о разине говорят, что он "шляпа" и что-то "прошляпил"?

Answer (score 3):

В Интернете нашла такую информацию, адрес http://chuliganka.livejournal.com/847939.html:

Шляпа. Прошляпить.

...Дольше всего искала происхождение выражения: “прошляпить”. Смысл этого выражения понятен: упустить что-либо, прозевать. “Шляпа” - так называют непрактичного или наивного человека, который упустил какую-то выгоду или человека, который мог, но не сделал то, что было возможно.

Но откуда пошло это выражение? Нашла три варианта:

1. Как указывает толковый словарь, шляпами встарь военные с пренебрежением называли гражданских.
2. Возможно, это действительно так, однако в словаре Даля такого значения у «шляпы» нет в принципе, а потому более правдоподобной выглядит версия о его более позднем происхождении. В соответствии с ней, шляпами именовали вовсе не военные штатских, а пролетарии – интеллигенцию, представители которой, согласно сложившемуся стереотипу, носили шляпы, тогда как на головах пролетариата в большинстве случаев красовались кепки.
3. Это выражение не имеет никакого отношения к головным уборам, мягкотелой интеллигенции и прочему. Словечко это пришло в жаргонную речь прямиком из идиша и является формой немецкого глагола «schlafen» – «спать». А «шляпа», соответственно, «соня, раззява». Пока вы тут шляпен, ваш чемодан драпен.
   Tags:
   занимательная этимология

Comment: История про гражданских, похоже, выдумана с начала и до конца.
Последяняя версия выглядит правдоподобной. Хотя обычно я против поиска еврейского следа в любом жаргонизме и идиоме, но тут просматривается вполне прозрачное значение.

Answer (score 2):

Прошляпить - от немецкого Schlappe (промах, неудача), а не от русского слова шляпа

Comment: А обосновать? ))